# Duplicating GreasePencilFrames changes their editing behaviour? (Bug?)

Tags: python, scripting, keyframes, grease-pencil, layers

Im instancing some `GreasePencilFrames` via code. With:

```
# Having a Greasepencil selected
gpd=bpy.context.active_object.data

layer = gpd.layers.active
frame = layer.active_frame
for i in range(5):
    f = layer.frames.copy(frame)
    f.keyframe_type = 'BREAKDOWN'
```

I have noticed that, when I execute the code **having the last frame active**, editing the strokes (in the duplicated frames via code) works as expected (changing a stroke in a certain frame only affect that specific frame).

[image]

HOWEVER, when I execute that same code having an active frame in between some frames, like, here:

[image]

Then, editing the strokes is "messed": When we edit (like simply move) a stroke, the changes affect all the following duplicated frames:

[image]

(Notice how other frames are changed after editing the active).

(Note: I do not have multiframe editing active)

Any idea about why this happens and how to make it work as in the first case?

Thank you so much for the help.

EDIT:

I noticed that when I move a stroke in edit mode, a new frame is created in the same place/time where the copied ones were created (they are overlaping (once I move one, there is one hidden in the same frame)). Is like the copy doesn't really creates the frames. Not sure if is a bug or I am doing something wrong.